# Control particular ul only using css

Tags: html, css

I have three dynamically creating ul under a div class.All three has same class name and li also has same class name.How can i control the second ul only using css.

```
<div class="main">
<ul class="level_0">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="level_0">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="level_0">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

please guide me...

Comment: I need to move the entire second ul only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a rule like

```
div.main ul:nth-of-type(2) {
   /* This will select 2nd ul */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AZPvX/)

Comment: not necessary for the code given, but may be necessary for the real code (especially given the naming convention used -- `level_0` implies that further nested levels may exist)

Comment: @Spudley Agreed, but I don't think, `nth-of-type` respects the element-class combination selection

Comment: Well imo it's ok to add a bit more specificity with `div.main ul.level_0:nth-of-type(2) {}`. Anyway +1 for da best answer here.

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ESjPA/1/)**

**Css code:**

```
ul:nth-child(2) {  
   color: #ccc;
}
```

a website with easy explanation: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: FAIL http://jsfiddle.net/ZPpd6/, `nth-child` will pick up any element which in on a 2nd position, so use `nth-of-type`, you can read my answer

Comment: thats not even my jsfiddle

Comment: I made it to show you how `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` is different

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nth-child selector:

```
ul:nth-child(2)
```

Doing so you select the second UL of it's parent.

More info here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: It would be better to point to [a reliable source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) rather than w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

You could give them a ID like:

```html
<ul class="level_0" ">
     <li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="level_0" id="nmbr_2">
     <li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="level_0" ">
     <li></li>
</ul>
```

and your css :

```css
#nmbr2{
   //style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.main .level_0:first-child + .level_0
```

For more Information 
[Adjacent-Selectors W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)